# recurrence relation for stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I was solving recurrence relation for stirling numbers of second kind

```
        S(n, k)                   if
-----------------------------------------
           1                  k=1 or k=n              
           0                  k=0 or k>n    
k*S(n-1, k) + S(n-1, k-1)     otherwise
```

substitution method is not working here because at every time k value changes ,
can anyone tell me what will be the correct method for this ,I just want to calculate the time complexity.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047552/recurrence-relation-for-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind

Answer (score 0):

If you write recursive code, time complexity will be O(2<sup>n</sup>/(sqrt(n)). But this problem can be solved by dynamic programming too which will take O(n*k) time.